# I keep getting this error in Eclipse when installing the Developer Tools and im not sure how to fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>
> **Software being installed:** Android Hierarchy Viewer
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>
> **Software currently installed:** Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
>   1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>
> **Only one of the following can be installed at once:** 
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
>       Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency:**
>       From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency:**
>       From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>       To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency:**
>       From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group
>   1.3.1.20100916-1202)
>       To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency:**
>       From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
>   3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
>       To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
>
> **Cannot satisfy dependency:**
>       From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group
>   3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
>       To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]

Any help would be great as i really want to start android development..

Thanks!!

Comment: I remember nights spent over fixing eclipse addons and bundles ..etc. I d just reinstall the eclipse and whatever you need..

Comment: It could happenned if you are not launching updates as admistrator/root, look at that : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339659

Answer (score 0):

ya either reinstall eclipse or you can try to update prior to installing the sdk.  in Eclipse go to

help>check for updates

i would also update your jdk (though stay at 6 if you can there are some bugs with 7 and eclipse (at least in my experience))

Answer (score 0):

I was running the Galileo version of eclipse and was running into the same issue. I upgraded java to the latest version of the sdk 6 which didn't fix the problem. Eclipse Juno is now out. I installed Juno and had no error messages when installing the Android ADT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to Help -> Install New Software. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.

Source: StackOverFlow: Pasting here as this Solution worked for me after trying a lot of solutions posted over net

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by removing all old Android plugins.  Once you have removed all of the old Android plugins you can then install the new ones.

1. Open Eclipse
2. Select Help
3. Select About Eclipse SDK
4. Select Installation details
5. Select all Android plugins &
6. Select Uninstall
7. Restart Eclipse
8. Then install the plugins again as normal
9. Restart Eclipse